# Reading from excel/text file without skipping whitespaces unless made by a tab

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I have a project on Power Plant Monitoring and it requires me to read in data from either of two files (an excel file or a text file). The data consists of 97 columns and 515 rows with a mixture of integers and strings. Hence, my idea was to declare 97 arrays to store the values in each column into their separate respective array. However, some columns contain strings with multiple words. Therefore one row may have one word in a column, while another row may have three etc. This is a problem because when I read in the rows, each string is assigned to a different string array when I want the programme to read the entire phrase as one string and store that string in the array initialised for that column. This causes the data to shift and some data is not assigned to the correct array etc.

I have a basic knowledge of C++, nothing spectacular but if I am not mistaken istreams stops reading when it meets a space and does not differentiate between tab spaces or normal spacebar spaces. Can anyone help me fix this problem so I could store the data properly and develop my KPIs?

I have included a portion of my data and also an attempt of trying to read in 4 columns of the code. Note that each column is separated by a tab in the text file version of the data.

```
ID Com NID  Plant                    Operator
3   N       Rock                     Alabama Elec Co
3   N       Rock                     Alabama Elec Co
4   N       Walt Boulder Co          Alabama Elec Co
10  N   3   Greene County            Alabama Elec Co    
46  N   1   Browns Ferry             Tennessee Valley Authority
```

ID Com NID  Plant                    Operator
3   N       Rock                     Alabama Elec Co
3   N       Rock                     Alabama Elec Co
4   N       Walt Boulder Co          Alabama Elec Co
10  N   3   Greene County            Alabama Elec Co
46  N   1   Browns Ferry             Tennessee Valley Authority

Illustrating the problem I am experiencing, if I have 4 string arrays for the four columns, in the first row, 3 would assign to array1, N to array2, Rock to array3 and Elec to array4. However, in row 3, 4 would assign to array1, N would assign to array2, Walt to array 3 but Boulder would assign to array 4 instead of the entire plant name being stored.
A similar fate occurs in row 5 which messes up the organisation of the data and does not allow me to manipulate it properly and accurately.

```
//numLines is taken from previous code to determine the 
//number of lines in the file
std::string *ID = new std::string[numLines]; 
std::string *YN = new std::string[numLines];
std::string *nuclearID = new std::string[numLines];
std::string *plantName = new std::string[numLines];

std::ifstream infile;
infile.open("nocommagenerationdata.dat");
if (infile.is_open()) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i<numLines) {
        infile >> ID[i] >> YN[i] >> nuclearID[i] >> plantName[i];
        std::cout << ID[i] << YN[i] << nuclearID[i] << plantName[i] << std::endl;

        i++;
    }

}
infile.close();
```

I also initially tried initialising a string with a counter to see if the data in one row lines up with the other but it clearly showed that the data shifted because of the selfsame reading in a string with a space problem.

```
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open("nocommagenerationdata.dat");
if (infile.is_open()) {
    int i = 0; std::string temp;
    while (i<numLines) {
        infile >> temp;
        std::cout << i << "." << temp << std::endl;

        i++;
    }

}
infile.close();
```

I would appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 0):

Just some hints.

Define a struct or class that represents the records you are reading from the file. You will only need one array to hold the records as they are constructed from each line in the file.

Investigate how to use std::getline to read each line in your file and std::strtok to parse each line for record data.

This will work for your tab-delimited text file. If your excel file is not tab-delimited, then you need to save a copy as tab-delimited.